# Android - Error when storing parsed xml data to sql

Tags: java, android, sql, xml, arraylist

I am getting a `java.lang.NullPointerException` error when storing xml data parsed from a URL on my localhost (http://10.0.0.22/cardealers.xml) to sql. Here is the xml am parsing:

```
<Providers>
  <CarDealer name="BEFORWARD" id="1">
    <CarMake name="Toyota" id="20">
      <CarModel name="Belta" id="21"/>
      <CarModel name="RunX" id="22"/>
      <CarModel name="Corolla" id="23"/>
    </CarMake>
    <CarMake name="Nissan" id="30">
      <CarModel name="Murano" id="31"/>
      <CarModel name="Pathfinder" id="32"/>
      <CarModel name="Navara" id="33"/>
    </CarMake>
  </CarDealer>
</Providers>
```

In my xml handler class, I passed my xml like so:

```
public class SAXXMLHandler extends DefaultHandler {
private List<CarMake> carMaker;
private String tempVal;
// to maintain context
private CarMake carmake;

public SAXXMLHandler() {

    carMaker = new ArrayList<CarMake>();
}

public List<CarMake> getCarMake() {

    return carMaker;
}

// Event Handlers
public void startElement(String uri, String localName, String qName,
                         Attributes attributes) throws SAXException {
    // reset
    tempVal = "";
    if (qName.equalsIgnoreCase("CarMake")) {
        // create a new instance of CarMake
        carmake = new CarMake();
        carmake.setName(attributes.getValue("name"));
    }
}

public void characters(char[] ch, int start, int length)
        throws SAXException {
    tempVal = new String(ch, start, length);
}

public void endElement(String uri, String localName, String qName)
        throws SAXException {

    if (qName.equalsIgnoreCase("CarMake")) {
        // add it to the list
        carMaker.add(carmake);
    } else if (qName.equalsIgnoreCase("CarModel")) {
        carmake.setCarModel(tempVal);
    }
 }
 }
```

Then using AsyncTask in `Sell.java`

```
public class Sell extends Activity implements
    View.OnClickListener, AdapterView.OnItemClickListener {

static final String URL = "http://10.0.0.22/cardealers.xml";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_sell);

    //new GetXMLTask().execute();
    new GetXMLTask(this).execute();
}

@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
                        long id) {
}

@Override
public void onClick(View view) {
    GetXMLTask task = new GetXMLTask(this);
    task.execute(new String[]{URL});
}

//private inner class extending AsyncTask
private class GetXMLTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, List<Service>> {
    private Activity context;

    public GetXMLTask(Activity context) {

        this.context = context;
    }

    /* uses HttpURLConnection to make Http request from Android to download
     the XML file */
    private String getXmlFromUrl(String urlString) {
        StringBuffer output = new StringBuffer("");
        try {
            InputStream stream = null;
            URL url = new URL(urlString);
            URLConnection connection = url.openConnection();

            HttpURLConnection httpConnection = (HttpURLConnection) connection;
            httpConnection.setRequestMethod("GET");
            httpConnection.connect();

            if (httpConnection.getResponseCode() == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
                stream = httpConnection.getInputStream();

                BufferedReader buffer = new BufferedReader(
                        new InputStreamReader(stream));
                String s = "";
                while ((s = buffer.readLine()) != null)
                    output.append(s);
            }

        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
        return output.toString();
    }


    @Override
    protected List<CarMake> doInBackground(String... urls) {
        List<CarMake> carMaker = null;
            String xml = null;

        for (String url : urls) {
            xml = getXmlFromUrl(url);

            InputStream stream = new ByteArrayInputStream(xml.getBytes());
            carMaker = SAXXMLParser.parse(stream);

        }
        // stream.close();
        return carMaker;
    }

     @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(List<CarMake> carMaker) {

        if (carMaker==null){
            Toast.makeText(Sell.this, "carMaker is empty..", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        } else {
            E_VodaDB myE_Voda = new E_VodaDB(this.context);
            myE_Voda.InsertData(carMaker);
        }
    }

  }
}
```

As can be seen, my `doInBackground()` returns a result, carMaker. Then in my `OnPostExecute()`, I am passing the `carMaker` arraylist to my databases class to insert in db.

```
// Adding new service
public void InsertData(List<CarMake> carMaker) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(CARMAKE_NAME, carMaker.get(0).getCarMake()); // CarMake Names

    // Inserting Row
    db.insert(TABLE_CARDEALER, null, values);
    db.close(); // Closing database connection
  }
}
```

I get the following error when I run the app in Android Studio:

`java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase android.content.Context.openOrCreateDatabase(java.lang.String, int, android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase$CursorFactory, android.database.DatabaseErrorHandler)' on a null object reference`

Pointing to my `Sell.java` in my `onPostExecute()`. It seems the `carMaker` arraylist returned from `doInBackground()` is empty or it is in a different data type that cannot be directly stored into db. How would I go about fixing this error? Please note am a newbie to android

Comment: `carMaker==null` Check before use.

Comment: where should I put that? In which class?

Comment: You should do the check before you use carMaker.get(0).  As that gives the null pointer exception. A good place is in onPostExecute(). Please add the code there so we can see what you do.

Comment: You changed your post, removed an exception and posted a new one. That is not how you should behave as now my comments about first exception are invalid. Why should i help you further?

Comment: no no no, I didn't change anything, like for real. Its still a `null object reference` except I added the full code for the error. Read it again

Comment: sorry if it appeared like I changed the question, please help if you can

Comment: You removed the call to get() on a null object wich was the cause of the exception. You now have a different cause. So my comment is invalid now.

Comment: @greenapps I added that code in `onPostExecute()`, now the error has changed. I am getting a `java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 0, Size: 0` on my `values.put(SERVICE_NAME, services.get(0).getService());`. Something am missing?

Comment: You did nod add any code to onPostExecute in your post. Show us what you are doing!

Comment: @greenapps I have updated the code `Sell.java` above. I have added the code with the changes I made to `onPostExecute()`. Have a look.

Comment: @greenapps the `onPostExecute()` is in `Sell.java` at the bottom of the class, if you can't see it.

Comment: Well is carMaker null? Do you see the toast? I would not say that a list is empty when it is null. It is only empty when it is not null and carMaker.size()==0. You could check for the latter too. As it does not make sense to continue if it is empty.

Answer (score 0):

on `doInBackground()` you create arraylist but forget to initialize. try this.

```
@Override
    protected List<CarMake> doInBackground(String... urls) {
        List<CarMake> carMaker = new ArrayList<CarMake>();
            String xml = null;

        for (String url : urls) {
            xml = getXmlFromUrl(url);

            InputStream stream = new ByteArrayInputStream(xml.getBytes());
            carMaker = SAXXMLParser.parse(stream);

        }
        // stream.close();
        return carMaker;
    }
```

you pass the null instance of current class context in this:

```
@Override
    protected void onPostExecute(List<CarMake> carMaker) {

        //E_DB myE_db = new E_DB(null);// replace this to 
          E_DB myE_db = new E_DB(this);
        myE_db.InsertData(carMaker);
    }

  }
```

Happy coding!!

Comment: umhm negative. The error is still there. Says `java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase android.content.Context.openOrCreateDatabase(java.lang.String, int, android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase$CursorFactory, android.database.DatabaseErrorHandler)' on a null object reference`

Comment: now your error is change, check your DB class. might be possible you forget to initialize variable.

Comment: @MannTazho why do u set null in E_DB myE_db = new E_DB(null);??

Comment: you were right, the `null` was a culprit. I have changed it to `E_VodaDB myE_Voda = new E_VodaDB(this.context);`. Now I am getting this error `android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near ")": syntax error (code 1): , while compiling: CREATE TABLE service(service_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL,service_name TEXT NOT NULL,stype TEXT ));`

Comment: @MannTazho ok cool if you find your problem by my post than mark as your answer.. happy to help you..!

Comment: @MannTazho check your syntax while creating table in your DB.

Comment: I checked syntax for creating db and made changes. Now am getting an error on `values.put(SERVICE_NAME, services.get(0).getService());`. The error says `java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 0, Size: 0`